# Spring RestController submit file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

As a part of a client request - image file must be submitted to my Spring `RestController` endpoint.

Is it possible to use `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file` with `RestController` ?

If so, could you please show an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and quite simple:

```
@RequestMapping("upload")
public void upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
  //Do what you like with the file
}
```